# Adding variables "by name" to local namespace

Tags: python, dictionary, namespaces, global, local

I know that I can add a variable to the global namespace "by name" with something like:

```
def getNewVar(name,val):
    globals()[name]=val
```

The things is, I would like to do this in a *local* namespace.  I have already tried and failed in using `locals()` instead of `globals()`.  Someone probably wants to know why I would do something like this.  OK, in my use case, the argument to the function is actually a dictionary, and I would like to do something like:

```
def processDictEntries(dict):
    for varname in dict.keys():
        locals()[varname]=dict[varname]  # won't work, of course
```

This way, further down in the function, I won't have to keep typing

```
result1=dict['var1']+5.
result2=dict['var2']*dict['var7']
```

over and over again.  I can just type

```
result1=var1+5
result2=var2*var7
```

And, if there is a way to do this in a small loop like I have written, then I don't have to do:

```
var1=dict['var1']
var2=dict['var2'] etc.
```

either.  I'm really just looking for economy of code; it's a big dictionary.

BTW, the entries of the dictionary are never altered; it is strictly input.  And, yes, I know that if the input dictionary lacks one of the variables the function needs, I will be in touble, but I think that can be dealt with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change how you call the function:

```
def processDictEntries(var1=None,var2=None,**kwargs):
    #do stuff with var1,var2 ...
```

And then call the function as:

```
processDictEntries(**dict)
```

and of course, if you can't do that, you can always use `processDictEntries` as a wrapper:

```
def _processDictEntries(var1=None,var2=None,**kwargs):
    ...

def processDictEntries(d):
    return _processDictEntries(**d)
```

---

<sup>As a side note, it's not a good idea to name a variable `dict` as then you shadow the builtin function</sup>